# integration of language translator in google app engine

Tags: timezone

Can anybody tell me how to integrate the language translator with Google App Engine?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Python GAE library for translations.  You didn't specify Java or Python in your question, but this should give you an idea of what keywords you can use to search for the platform of your choice:

http://code.google.com/p/appengine-framework/wiki/MultiLanguage